# Django ошибка выгрузки дампа с json формата

Tags: python, django

С помощью команды создаю дамп

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > current_project_dump.json
```

Переношу дамп в проект без бд, делаю новую миграцию, запускаю команду для выгрузки бд из json формата

```
python3 manage.py loaddata project_dump.json
```

Выводит ошибку

```
Problem installing fixture '/Users/user/site/project_dump.json': Could not load wagtailcore.Page(pk=3): UNIQUE constraint failed: wagtailcore_page.
```

Вырезка из json для `wagtailcore.page`

```
{
"model": "wagtailcore.page",
"pk": 3,
"fields": {
    "path": "00010001",
    "depth": 2,
    "numchild": 5,
    "title": "Home",
    "draft_title": "Home",
    "slug": "home",
    "content_type": [
        "home",
        "homepage"
    ],
    "live": true,
    "has_unpublished_changes": false,
    "url_path": "/home/",
    "owner": [
        "admin"
    ],
    "seo_title": "Bla bla bla",
    "show_in_menus": false,
    "search_description": "Bla bla bla.",
    "go_live_at": null,
    "expire_at": null,
    "expired": false,
    "locked": false,
    "first_published_at": "2018-03-06T07:02:55.872Z",
    "last_published_at": "2018-03-21T15:02:13.111Z",
    "latest_revision_created_at": "2018-03-21T15:02:13.066Z",
    "live_revision": 125
}
```

},

Answer (score 1):

Как было очевидно из сообщения об ошибке - есть повторяемое уникальное значение. Это было потому что wagtail библиотека автоматически генерирует запись с homepage в базе данных со значениями по-умолчанию. Решением было удаление дефолтной страницы из базы, перенос данных из дампа и изменение ключа-ссылки на homapage.